# Enterprise distribution fails

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a problem when installing an app through item-services: "Could not install at this moment"

In device logs I can see this:

```
Jan 16 14:26:22 iPad-4 SpringBoard[43] <Warning>: Killing com.organisation.lalala for app installation
Jan 16 14:26:22 iPad-4 itunesstored[81] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder <LSApplicationProxy: 0x166f6370> com.organisation.lalala (Placeholder)
Jan 16 14:26:22 iPad-4 itunesstored[81] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x166f6370> com.organisation.lalala (Placeholder) withPhase:1
Jan 16 14:26:22 iPad-4 lsd[72] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installState for parent <NSProgress: 0x14ea8780> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9800 / Completed: 98 of 100   to LSInstallStateWaiting
Jan 16 14:26:22 iPad-4 lsd[72] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: 0x14ea8780> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9800 / Completed: 98 of 100   to 1
Jan 16 14:26:22 iPad-4 installd[36] <Notice>: 0x1d45000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/2254137808045488130/-6393278779922071210" type Customer requested by itunesstored (pid 81)
Jan 16 14:26:23 iPad-4 installd[36] <Error>: 0x1d45000 +[MIInstallable installablesAtURL:packageFormat:userOptions:error:]: 52: Failed to inspect package at file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.gorFAA/extracted (Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "_IterateDirectory for file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.gorFAA/extracted/Payload returned No such file or directory" UserInfo=0x16db0bf0 {FunctionName=-[MIFileManager urlsForItemsInDirectoryAtURL:error:], SourceFileLine=413, NSLocalizedDescription=_IterateDirectory for file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.gorFAA/extracted/Payload returned No such file or directory})
Jan 16 14:26:23 iPad-4 itunesstored[81] <Error>: 0x220c000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke240: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=6 "Failed to inspect package at file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.gorFAA/extracted" UserInfo=0x166e99b0 {LegacyErrorString=PackageInspectionFailed, FunctionName=+[MIInstallable installablesAtURL:packageFormat:userOptions:error:], NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to inspect package at file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.gorFAA/extracted, SourceFileLine=52, NSUnderlyingError=0x166db1a0 "_IterateDirectory for file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.gorFAA/extracted/Payload returned No such file or directory"}
Jan 16 14:26:23 iPad-4 itunesstored[81] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
Jan 16 14:26:23 iPad-4 lsd[72] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app com.organisation.lalala
Jan 16 14:26:23 iPad-4 itunesstored[81] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.organisation.lalala.Installing - <NSProgress: 0x1660ffa0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
```

This is modification of Siphon app. If I install it through xcode it works fine.
I could not find any solution...

Comment: I have same issue. See the log and make sure your IPA contains Payload folder when renamed to .zip and uncompressed. Recent IPAs contain the app inside Applications/ folder instead of Payload/ and this seems to cause the issue (IPA package format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. The comment from igraczech led me to the solution.

1. Rename the file from appname.ipa to appname.zip.
2. Unzip the zipfile. The folder name should be "Application".
3. Rename the folder to "Payload".
4. Compress to zip file again.
5. Rename the zip archive to appname.ipa
6. Now it works!

I found some further Information here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2318/_index.html

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why but in ipa I had "Users/%username%/Applications/" catalog structure. Leftiing only Applications and renaiming it to Payload helped!

Comment: After following those steps the payload missing error continues in my case :(

Comment: What does the document structure inside your ipa file look like nano?

Answer (score 1):

In the application plist file, set this value to Yes. 
"Application requires iPhone environment", this will create the payload folder instead of application